# What happens when mysql binlog reaches mysql-bin.999999

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysqlbinlog, binlog

Lets say my mysql replication is enabled for long time, and the server has been quite busy, so new bin log files get created every few seconds. So in a few months, it is possible for latest bin log file to have name "mysql-bin.999999". Does the next file again become "mysql-bin.000001"?

The question is important from check pointing view, since I'm using the replication to stream changes of the DB. If the name starts back from 000001, then I cannot assume that file names would be always incrementing, so if older record are received, then it cannot be ignored just because file name is numerically smaller.

Comment: It will continue up to INT_MAX, which should suffice for the next month or two.

Comment: So does that mean it would "rotate" back to 0000001?

Comment: No, it will continue to 2147483647. Then it throws an error (unless you purged older files). You might want to prepare for that.

Comment: I'm storing just last 1 days worth of data. So lets say there are a 100K bin log files when it reaches INTMAX. Then what happens?

Comment: As I said, if you have used up 2 billion indexes (58 years of 100K files/day), it will stop with an error. You will then have to reset it. Is this a real concern? It sounds more like you should rethink a process that relies on 100k binlogs/day, but has to rely on the filename to work properly. There are about 2 billion other things that can go wrong before that (e.g. someone changing the binlog filename/stopping replication/some error in replication; mysql (if it still exists) changing the log format in the next 50 years (and not increasing that max number); skynet taking over your server).

Comment: Thanks Solarflare, I just wanted to understand what exactly would happen. Although its not entirely unlikely to have that kind of load on a RDB.

Comment: The next log file after `mysql-bin.999999` is definitely  `mysql-bin.1000000`.  You do, however, need to ensure that you are comparing the actual numbers numerically and not doing a lexical (string) comparison... because '1' < '9'.